# 'System.Data.Entity.Database' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteStoredProcedure'

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework extras EF6 in Visual Studio 2013 for calling a stored procedure that takes table valued parameter.

But on this line of code:

```
context.Database.ExecuteStoredProcedure(procedure);
```

I get this error:

> 'System.Data.Entity.Database' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteStoredProcedure' and no extension method 'ExecuteStoredProcedure' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.Database' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear that tells you, there is no method definition like `ExecuteStoredProcedure`. You could execute the stored procedure using `SqlQuery`;

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<YourEntityClass>("procedureName",params);
```

Comment: I want to pass table as parameter. And as i mentioned i am using entity framework extras EF 6. It is package available in nuget.

Comment: What is that "entity framework extras" package. I couldn't see any mentioned package.